# Sed, use previous search result in replace

Tags: regex, sed

Syntatic example.
Input file

```
help_key1
man_key1
result_key1

help_key2
man_key2

help_key3
result_key3

help_key4
```

I can get all keys with

> sed -n -e 's/help_(.*)$/\1/p'

How I can use match \1 in other search or replace?

Question 1: How I can filter keys which have help and result prefix? Result as:

> key1 key3

Question 2: How I can filter keys which have help and man and result prefix? Result as:

> key1

Use only sed, without bash.

Comment: are a blank line after any keyi set?

Comment: you need to load the whole file or at least section in buffer before making the test of content. As you write "prefix", you mean that the prefix is know (in a variable for example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

help and result

```
sed -n '/^help_.*/,/^$/ {
   /^help_/ h
   /^help_}/ !H
   x
   /help_\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\(\n.*\)*\nresult_\1.*/ {
      s//\1/p
      b
      }
   x
   }' YourFile
```

adding man

```
sed -n '/^help_.*/,/^$/ {
   /^help_/ h
   /^help_}/ !H
   /^$/ b test
   $ b test
   b
: test
   x
   /help_\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\(\n.*\)*\nresult_\1.*/ {
      /help_\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\(\n.*\)*\nman_\1.*/ {
         s//\1/p
         b
         }
      }
   }' YourFile
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest `awk` since its good for working with group data.
Question 1:

```
awk  -v RS="" -F_ '/help/ && /result/ {print $2}' file
key1
key3
```

In `awk` you can set Record Selector to nothing.  This make it work with groups of lines, separated by a blank line.

---

Question 2:

```
awk -v RS="" -F_ '/help/ && /man/ && /result/ {print $2}' file
key1
```

If order are always the same you can do:

```
awk -v RS="" -F_ '/help.*man.*result/ {print $2}' file
key1
```

Comment: (you forget "result" in the second question) awk is the best solution in this case +1

Comment: @NeronLeVelu fixed question `2`

Comment: not sur :-) case of help/result/man is not taken (but not present nor specify in description i agree)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to bash

```
    words={a,n,t}{a,n,t}{a,n,t}{'\n'}
    echo $words
```

Outputs:

aaa
aan
aat

and so on.  The output can be passed through **sort** and usr/dict if required.  This is called ' brace expansion' , and some other languages have it.

My favourite is echo {a,i}{s,t} gives "as at is it"

I am guessing you are using this for Scrabble ;)